# What's the point of having private constructors if you can access them with reflection?

Tags: .net, reflection, access-modifiers

and maybe private static method and properties, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Access modifiers help direct program flow. They are like traffic signals - you don't have to obey them, and in certain situations authorized players may choose to ignore them, but you usually want to respect them because they make everything run much more smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

Private constructors are often used with design patterns (eg. [Factory Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) ) to prevent objects being incorrectly instantiated.

Private static methods are often faster to call if you don't need to access any instance variables (the compiler doesn't have to check the object is non-null among other things).

Answer (score 2):

Reflection is recognized as a more powerful than usual way to access your classes - recommendations are that non-public access be denied for uncontrolled code - see [ReflectionPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.reflectionpermission.aspx).

> Without ReflectionPermission, code can
>   use reflection to access only the
>   public members of objects. Code with
>   ReflectionPermission and the
>   appropriate ReflectionPermissionFlag
>   flags can access the protected and
>   private members of objects.
>
> Caution
>
> Because ReflectionPermission
>   can provide access to non-public types
>   and members, we recommend that you do
>   not grant ReflectionPermission to
>   Internet code, except with the
>   ReflectionPermissionFlag.RestrictedMemberAccess
>   flag. RestrictedMemberAccess allows
>   access to non-public members, with the
>   restriction that the grant set of the
>   non-public members must be equal to,
>   or a subset of, the grant set of the
>   code that accesses the non-public
>   members.

In other words, people only access your class internals if you let them - just the same as with setting access modifiers in the first place, for direct clients with an assembly reference.  Any member is only visible if you let it be visible.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is different in the Silverlight runtime, where basically reflection can only do what the compiler (C# or VB) is allowed to.
So in Silverlight, you can not instantiate using a private constructor, even with Activator.CreateInstance.